# Spring Data REST: create entity with @DbRef field

Tags: spring, spring-data-rest

I have two entities:

```
class User {

@DbRef
private Form form; 

}

class Form {
}
```

And REST repositories `@RepositoryRestResource` for both of them.

I want to create new `User` resource, so I'm doing `POST` request with next json:

```
{
   "form":"/forms/123"
}
```

Where `"/forms/123"` is a resource reference. But it doesn't work.
It says `"Could not read document: Can not construct instance of User: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value"`

Should I enable something to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the full URL, e.g.

```
{
   "form": "http://localhost:8080/forms/123"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that. I was looking for this information everywhere. Spring Data Rest documentation doesn't have it. Do you remember where this feature is described? In what document you have learned?